# PGP encrypting emails sent to a specific former PGP user

Tags: pgp-desktop

I am new to PGP Desktop but I have a few users that have it installed. One of my users recently had it reinstalled. She is running PGP Desktop 9.8/outlook 07. Whenever she emails one specific user that previously had PGP installed years ago, it encrypts the message being sent to him. He cannot read these messages being sent because he no longer is running PGP. He is not in her list of users that she shares keys with but it still encrypts the message to him before sending.  I have googled around for some assistance but have not found any answers that could help. Is there someone that could point me in the right direction? Is there somewhere else that this data is stored?

Comment: I think they could just do a new key exchange and all would be well.. But the guy not running PGP would need to start

Comment: Thats the thing the guy not running pgp doesnt want to start. Just so he can receive these messages.

Comment: Maybe you can work out her setup to not bother sending pgp to that guy then. Does she have a key for him that you can disable?